# Numerical issues with matrix exponential for diagonalizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am learning about computation of matrix exponentials, and have come across the technique:

$$ e^A = U \operatorname{diag}(e^{\lambda_1}, e^{\lambda_2}, \ldots, e^{\lambda_n}) U^{-1}$$

Where the $\lambda_i$s are given by the eigenvalues of $A$, and $U$ is given by the eigenvectors.

Obviously this only works for diagonalizable matrices. Other than that, are there any reasons why this would not be a good algorithm from a numerical sense? The only thing I can think of is perhaps having to compute $U^{-1}$ is undesirable? I know that generally speaking it's not the best to have to invert a matrix from a numerical standpoint. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: here is an article on numerical issues http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/researchpdf/19ways+.pdf